# setting value is changing key name

Tags: javascript, object, key, overwrite

```
var test = {
    one: {},
    two: {},
};
test['two'].parent = test['one'];
```

what i want test to have:

```
test = {
   one: {},
   two: { parent: {}, }
```

what it actually has:

```
 test = {
    parent: {},
    two: { parent: {}, }
```

why does test.one become test.parent?

I want test.two.parent to hold a reference to test.one. how would i do this?

Comment: What makes you think that that's happening?  It isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does test.one become test.parent?

It doesn't. The resulting structure is:

```
{
one: {},
two: { parent: {} }
}
```

Where `parent` is referencing the same object as referenced by `one`.

If you do:

```
test.one.cheese = "crackers";
```

...the result below will be "crackers"

```
alert(test.two.parent.cheese); // "crackers"
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/g5chF/

Comment: sorry you are correct, my issue was in the debugger which clearly has a bug which showed me the above output

Answer (score 3):

What browser are you using? It may make a difference.

I am receiving expected results testing in Firebug on Firefox, however I wouldn't suggest mixing and matching property access syntax (syntaxes? syntaxen?).

Instead of:

```
test['two'].parent = test['one'];
```

I would do:

```
test['two']['parent'] = test['one'];
```

Comment: Totally unnecessary; either way of accessing or defining the properties will work.

Comment: @Pointy, I mentioned that the original worked, the rest was a suggestion to remain consistent.

Comment: OK well I guess that's a good point.  `test.two.parent = test.one` would also work here.

Answer (score 1):

Your claim as to what this statement does:

```
test['two'].parent = test['one'];
```

is incorrect. The code already does what you want: it adds a "parent" attribute to `test.two`, so that there'll be an empty object at `test.two.parent`.